# Enable surge requirement for computational power, but low power otherwise

Tags: performance, power-management

New laptops prolong battery life by going into low performance when running on batteries.  I notice this tremendously when running a computational analysis.  However, those runs are short, and done sporadically.

Is there a way to let CPU execution run as fast as when plugged in, but only when there is demand for computation power?  When I'm not running those analyses, the throttled performance is more than enough.

I'm on Windows 10 Professional.  I'm not sure if it's under OS or machine control (if such a control even exists), but I'm using an HP Elitebook 840 G6.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the power plan in the *Power Options* applet to High performance,
but there is no way to make it adaptable to the current work load.

This will mean that the battery will drain faster, unless you manually switch
power plans whenever usage goes up or down.

Comment: Thanks, harrymc.  I suspect that your answer is right, but I'd like to hold off on marking it such for now in the slim hope that someone might surprise us.  For some reason, I was expecting that we'd be much further along with processor design, but I can't really think of specific reasons why.

Comment: Modern processors do regulate their power automatically, independent from the operating system. On idle, core power usage can drop by an order of magnitude. On heavy usage, turbo mode will kick in with larger power usage. Because of this, High performance mode won't be the disaster it would have been years ago. Try it to see how this works in your laptop.